# Вывести массивом курс валют (API)

Tags: php, api

Доброго времени суток, есть скрипт который подключается средством API к банку и выводит курс валют, скрипт выводит только одну валюту USD, как вывести массивом сразу три валюты USD, EUR, RUR?

```
function _isCurl(){ 
  return function_exists('curl_version'); 
  }

function get_course(){
    if (_iscurl()){ //curl is enabled 
  $url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5"; 
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
  $output = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch); 
 // print_r($output); // Curl operations finished 
 if(!$output) return false;


  $courses = json_decode($output,true);
  $course_curr = false;
  } else{ 
  echo "CURL is disabled"; 
  } 
  $curr = 'USD'; //Выводит доллары
foreach($courses as $course){
    if($course['ccy']==$curr){
        $course_curr = $course['buy'];


    }
}
    return $course_curr;
}


$course_curr = get_course();

print_r($course_curr).'<br />';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему, ответ очевиден:

```
$curr = 'USD'; //ВЫВОДИТ ДОЛЛАРЫ
foreach($courses as $course){
    if($course['ccy']==$curr){
        $course_curr = $course['buy'];
    }
}
```

Нужно изменить на:

```
$curr = ['USD','EUR','RUR']; // 'USD','EUR','RUR'
foreach($courses as $course){
    if(in_array($course['ccy'], $curr)){
        $course_curr[$course['ccy']] = $course['buy'];
    }
}
```

Перед вопросом, желательно разобраться с кодом

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно было